# Display time elapsed time from the point of function start

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display time elsapsed from the point of current start, but my below code displays from the epoch.I am looking to display minutes and seconds and only if it exceeds it would show hours, this means it should start displaying seconds and after 59s it show display as minutes seconds and so on.

So I tried to modify the count down timer function of w3schools. Unfortunately that didnt work.

How do I modify to display time elapsed instead of countdown?

```html
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() + 30000;
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate + now; // changed to plus but that didnt work

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can modify the code slightly to show a timer that counts up rather than down. We'll create a `startDate` variable to hold the Date we start counting from. To get the number of milliseconds elapsed since this time, we subtract `now` from `startDate`. The rest of the code is basically the same as above!

```html
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var startDate = new Date().getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = (now - startDate);

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  const units = ['d', 'h', 'm', 's'];
  const html = [days, hours, minutes, seconds].map((el, idx) => { 
       return el ? el + units[idx]: '';
  }, []).join(' ');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;
}, 1000)


</script>
```